# coordinator status is unavailable in Infinispan cluster

Tags: infinispan, jgroups

We are using Inifinispan cluster with jgroups-tcp configuration in one of our setups. Sometimes we are observing that the coordinator status in jconsole is showing as **unavailable**, but this is not affecting any of the functionality.  However, I'm just curious as in why the status is showing as unavailable. Any pointers would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What Infinispan version? The console still shows `coordinatorAddress` property, so in theory, that should give you all the info you need about the coordinator.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the type of `coordinator` cannot be displayed by jconsole. E.g. if the type was `org.jgroups.Address`, then this class would have to be added to the classpath used by jconsole.

Actually, I'm not sure about my last statement, but googling for jconsole and custom types might be helpful.

This is not JGroups-specific.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Bela Ben. We have observed that this error is coming coming intermittently. If it is related to class-path, then we should be getting it all the time,right?